# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I'm using AWS and I have requested an ACM certificate. I used DNS validation to make it a valid cert. Now I've attached it to a private ALB.

The URL is private.

When I connect with my VPN and I can perform the following command:

```
curl -vvI https://mystuff.domain.cloud 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
```

Output:

```
..*  SSL certificate verify ok.
..
```

When I visit the URL in Firefox everything is fine too and it's a valid cert.
But when I visit the URL in Chrome I see the following error:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

The Certificate is not valid is shown. When I click on that I see the Amazon Root CA 1 (valid), Amazon intermediate cert (valid) and `mystuff.domain.cloud` cert (valid). Everything seems valid there..

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm searching for hours and I don't get it. I also contacted AWS support but everything on cert and AWS side was fine.

Comment: Hi, does the error come from other computers too ? to isolate if it's a custom chrome settings, or a certificate imported inside the machine that was set that cause the error.

Comment: BTW a simpler way to select all lines from a pattern to EOF is `...| awk '/^\* SSL connection/,0'` or sed can do it `...| sed -n '/^\* SSL connection/,$p'`